# Posting photo to a FB page as admin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is my snippet so far

```
function upload(url) {
FB.api('/PAGE_ID', {
    fields: 'id, access_token'
}, function (response) {
    var page_id = response.id;
    var access_token = response.access_token;
    FB.api('/' + page_id + '/photos', 'post', {
        'message': '',
        'access_token': access_token,
        'url': url
    }, function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        $("#upload_input").val("");
        alert("uploaded!");
    });
});
```

}

This uploads a photo as if the page posted it. So it appears 'Published by page_name' directly on the feed.
I don't know why these photos doesn't reach any people as the photos I upload from fb. (ones that shows 'Published by admin_name').

How do I post photos directly to WALL so it appears 'Published by admin_name' exactly how is on Facebook.
If I remove the access_token it will upload to the 'Photos posted to the page' album

> Edit: I have the following permissions scope:'publish_actions,
>   manage_pages, publish_pages'

Comment: _“I don't know why these photos doesn't reach any people”_ – is your app “live” (switch on top of Status&Review tab in app dashboard)? You need to make it live/available to all users – otherwise, all content created via your app will only be visible to app admins/developers/testers.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik posts made with the API usually will not get as visible as manually posted stuff. You can´t do anything about that, you can only check if it looks correct on your Page - which is the case, according to your explanation. Facebook decides about the reach, with a complicated algorithm.

Btw, you only need `publish_pages` and `manage_pages`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code which is working fine for me, try running this:

```js
function uploadPhotoOnPage(){
  FB.api(
      "/{you page-id here}/photos",
      "POST",
      {
          "url": "http://www.arlnews.com/uploads/3/8/1/0/38109169/5121906_orig.jpg"
      },
      function (response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
          alert("Photo could not be uploaded");
        } else{
    alert("Photo Successfully uploaded on page whose id is " + response.id);
   }
      }
  );
}
```

and make a button for this and call the function from that button